# How to enumerate all logged in user sessions from a launch daemon on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, usersession, launch-daemon

From an interactive user session for a logged in user I can use [SessionGetInfo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1593382-sessiongetinfo?language=objc) function to obtain the calling process' session ID:

```
SecuritySessionId sessID;
SessionAttributeBits flags;

if(SessionGetInfo(callerSecuritySession,
                             &sessID,
                             &flags) == errSecSuccess)
{
    printf("session ID=%d", sessID);
}
```

But how do I enumerate all such session IDs from my launch daemon? Or session IDs for all currently logged in users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a badly documented `utmpx.h` set of functions. And for that specific reason you would need to use `setutxent`, `getutxent`, `endutxent` functions. Check a code [example here](https://dennisbabkin.com/blog/?t=macos-programming-critical-sections-reader-writer-locks-login-sessions-root-strings#login_sessions).